# Remove Server : istio-envoy header in Istio 1.8.2

Tags: istio

How can I remove the server header generated by Istio ?

In Istio 1.5.6 I had an Istio EnvoyFilter, but that doesn't seem to work anymore in Istio 1.8.2.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: dgp-headerstrip-server
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
    match:
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
    patch:
      operation: MERGE
      value:
        config:
          server_header_transformation: PASS_THROUGH
```

Comment: Have you tried to replace envoy.http_connection_manager with envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager ?  https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/29858#issuecomment-758298344

Comment: Yes, but is doesn't work; also tried the typed_config value (https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/13861) but that doesn't work either :-(

Answer (score 1):

Solved : use typed_config (https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/13861)

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: dgp-headerstrip-server
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
    match:
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
    patch:
      operation: MERGE
      value:
        typed_config:
          '@type': type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager
          server_header_transformation: PASS_THROUGH
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the deprecated warning, tested with Istio 1.9

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: remove-server-header
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
    match:
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
    patch:
      operation: MERGE
      value:
        typed_config:
          '@type': type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          server_header_transformation: PASS_THROUGH
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also **set, add, remove** a header directly from Istio, with a `VirtualService` object?

**Example**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: reviews-route
spec:
  hosts:
  - reviews.prod.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - headers:
      request:
        set:
          test: "true"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: reviews.prod.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v2
      weight: 25
    - destination:
        host: reviews.prod.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v1
      headers:
        response:   # this is from the response, but you can put it in the request as well.
          remove:
          - foo
      weight: 75
```

Header [parameters](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#Headers-HeaderOperations).

Comment: Does this work for 'special' headers like 'Server' ?

Comment: @PeterClaes I would say with any header. Just write the key of the header under remove, and it should remove the header.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Istio-1.9.0 version, to remove the response headers, you will have to apply envoy filter configuration onto the Kubernetes cluster, then you must be add it in the Virtual service otherwise it wont work.

Along with **remove** we can also add **set, add** for modifications and adding the headers

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: remove-server-header
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
      match:
        context: GATEWAY
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        value:
          typed_config:
            '@type': type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager
            server_header_transformation: PASS_THROUGH
```

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: x-api-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - {{ .Values.domain }}
  - {{ .Values.serviceName }}
  gateways:
  - istio-system/istio-ingressgateway
  http:
    - match:
        - port: 80
      route:
      - destination:
            host: {{ .Values.serviceName }}
            subset: x-v1-app  
            port:
               number: {{ .Values.service.servicePort }}
      headers:
        response: 
          remove:
          - Server
---
kind: DestinationRule
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
metadata:
  name: x-api-dr-rules
spec:
  host: {{ .Values.serviceName }}
  subsets:
    - labels:
        version: v1
      name: x-v1-app
```

Istio documentation https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#Headers-HeaderOperations